# mojarra jsf api / impl 2.1.12 prints out css comments

Tags: jsf, mojarra

i switched the implementation from 2.1.3 up to 2.1.12 mojarry.
But now i can see in any IE Explorers the CSS switch comments:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 7]> <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; padding:0 0 0 0px; position:         relative;'> <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img  src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/../resources/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today. /></a> </div> <![endif]--> <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->
```

is now visible instead off rendering this.
Means, in my source code the characters  get escaped with lt and gt.
this comes from the api change. does someone had the same expierence ?
thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<h:outputText escape="false">` to render it the way you want:

```
<h:outputText value="&lt;!--[if lt IE 7]&gt;&lt;div&gt;...&lt;/div&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;" escape="false" />
```

Or you can use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:conditionalComment>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/conditionalComment) to keep it less scary:

```
<o:conditionalComment if="lt IE 7">
    <div>...</div>
</o:conditionalComment>
```

Comment: thanks BalusC, this is an option but not the way it should usually goes. can you confirm, that this is a bug ? thanks and regards